# Start sreen with 3 windows

Tags: terminal

Sorry if this is duplicate, but my search did not help to answer this.
I need to start `screen` with `vi file1.js` in one tab, `vi file2.js` in other tab, and `node myserver.js` in the third tab. The first tab should be selected. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

create screen config file `config`:

```
welcome_message off
caption always "%-w%{+b kw}%t%{-}%+w"    
screen bash -c "vi server.js"
screen bash -c "vi config.txt"
```

start screen:

```
screen -c config
```